# ¿Cómo puede detener el puerto 8080 con PID 4 de mi sistema?, Spring no levanta

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cmd, puertos

Estoy ejecutando un proyecto en Spring pero me sale error, el puerto 8080 con PID 4 ya esta siendo usado. ¿Como puedo parar ese puerto que ya se esta ejecutando en el sistema?

```
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1008) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:263) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:195) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:296) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.hregional.springboot.backend.apirest.SpringBootBackendApirestApplication.main(SpringBootBackendApirestApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_211]


    Description:
    
    The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.
    
    Action:
    
    Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

Lo revise en el cmd y me sale lo siguiente:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netstat -ano|findstr "PID :8080"
  Proto  Dirección local          Dirección remota        Estado           PID
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
```

Intente eliminar el PID 4, pero no me deja

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>taskkill /F /PID 4
Error: no se pudo terminar el proceso con PID 4.
Motivo: Acceso denegado.
```

Comment: si estoy ejecutando como administrador

Comment: Agrega la opción b al netstat para que muestre el nombre del ejecutable que tiene capturado el puerto, puede que sea un proceso de sistema. Una solución provisória podría cambiar el puerto del tomcat

Comment: Parece que tienes otra aplicación ocupando ese puerto. Si no tienes permisos para matarlo es porque es probable que esté corriendo como servicio. Por otro lado, el proceso 4 es `System`, que encapsula a gran cantidad de procesos y servicios, por lo que te será difícil indagar más sin comprobar los servicios que tienes instalados en la máquina. ¿Has instalado el servidor apache como servicio usando `apache -k`? Si es así, para el servicio con `sc stop apache2.4` (o el nombre con el que se haya creado el servicio).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes acceder a Windows PowerShell como administrador y ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
Stop-Process (, (-ano -an | findstr: 8080) .split() | foreach {$ [$ .length-1]}) -Force
```

o

```
Stop-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 8080) .OwningProcess -Force
```